# Proving Density Function, Integrating

Tags: probability, statistics, functions

question:

[image]

I understand that the integral of $f(x)$ in this instance is $F(x)$ as it is the cdf of the pdf $f(x)$. So shouldn't $\int f(x)dx$ be $F(x)$?

The below is taken from the answers, which show that $\int f(x)dx = F(x)-1$.

What am I missing here?

$$\int_{x_{0}}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{1-F(x_{0})} dx = \frac{F(x)-1}{1-F(x_{0})}\Bigg|_{x_{0}}^\infty$$

Comment: $\int f(x)dx$ needs limits: as an indefinite integral it would be $F(x)+c$.  With limits $\int\limits_{a}^b f(x)dx = F(b)-F(a)$ and here $\int\limits_{x_0}^\infty f(x)dx = 1-F(x_0)$

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{x_{0}}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{1-F(x_{0})} dx = \frac1 {1-F(x_0)}\int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(x)dx=\frac  {1-F({x_0})} {1-F(x_0)}=1$$

Comment: Thanks Kavi, that's what I thought the answer should be but, does that mean the answer displaying F(infinity) -1 is wrong, and should be the other way around?

Comment: Indeed, Kavi is saying that that answer should be : $$\int_{x_{0}}^\infty \dfrac{f(x)}{1-F(x_{0})}~\mathrm dx = \left.\dfrac{F(x)}{1-F(x_{0})}\right|_{x_{0}}^\infty~=\dfrac{1-F(x_0)}{1-F(x_{0})}$$